# plot the values of list in df in r

Tags: r

suppose i have the following df

| dataset | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | c(1,3,4,5,2) |
| 2 | c(7,8,1,2,3) |
| 3 | c(4,11,10,3,2) |

I want a graph with x axis numbers 1 to 5 corresponding to the size of the list of values, and in y axis the list values. The resulting graph must have 3 different lines corrsponding to each dataset.

I'm trying with

```
    ggplot(df,aes(x=c(1:5),y=values,color=dataset) + geom_line()
```

but i have this error : Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): x and y

the problem is that is taking y as length 1 list.

Comment: please provide your data by pasting the output of `dput(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may `unnest` the data, create the `x` column and then plot -

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  unnest(values) %>%
  group_by(dataset) %>%
  mutate(x = row_number(), 
         dataset = factor(dataset)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, values, color = dataset)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(dataset = 1:3, values = list(c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2), 
    c(7, 8, 1, 2, 3), c(4, 11, 10, 3, 2))), 
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```